# Upgrade DATABASE in Android App

Tags: android, database

I want to upgrade the DATABASE of my Android App, without losing data that users saved in a specific table (say "favourites" table, where I store the _id of "food" entries).

I'm simplyfing the structure of my DB to keep the code in this question shorter, anyway I'm using **SQLiteAssetHelper** and a **ContentProvider**

When I tried to upgrade the DataBase I received the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2
```

Here my DB Helper class

```
public class CookingDBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cookingDB.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public CookingDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    super.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);

}
```

}

Let's say I have two tables in my DB: "food" table I want to upgrade, and "favourites" table I want to preserve it as the user saved.
Here the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "food" (
`_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT,
`category_id`   INTEGER,)

CREATE TABLE "favourites" (
`_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`id_favourite`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(`id_favourite`) REFERENCES food ( _id )
```

)

Could you please tell me how I can upgrade the food table without losing the favourites saved by the user?

Comment: do you call `getReadableDatabase()` anywhere? Don't. Ever. Only if you have a static database that never ever needs to change or upgrade.

Comment: Yes I call it in my ContentProvider, in public Cursor query() method.
Should I use getWritableDatabase() ?

Comment: Yes, writeable is basically always required since the openhelper needs to write to the database during opening in certain cases. Even if you do only read only queries afterwards. Edit: it's apparently still the case that getReadable() will try to give you a writeable one because of exactly this problem https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29 - I don't know how you manage to actually get a read-only database then.

Comment: I replaced with getWritableDatabase(), but I still have the error:
Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: no upgrade script path from 2 to 3

Comment: you need to provide upgrade scripts https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#database-upgrades (containing statements like [`ALTER TABLE food ADD COLUMN.. `](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) etc - in case you need to do things that can't be done via altering: copy to a temporary table like in the example on github)

Comment: I provided the script.sql but I receive the same error.
Moreover, for the moment I'm trying just to add records to the table and not to alter the structure of the table

Comment: Here it's how the script looks like:

BEGIN TRANSACTION;


DROP TABLE android_metadata;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

(It is the only change in the db, all the others are records added)

Comment: That error should go away as soon as you have `assets/databases/cookingDB.db_upgrade_2-3.sql` in your project. You also seem to have increased your `DATABASE_VERSION` in your helper to 3. A bunch of `INSERT` statements are enough in that script when you want to add data. And don't delete the `android_metadata` table unless you know why you're doing that, it's autogenerated by android and holds for some internals.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Your Apps In the Emulator or Phone And Re-install Your Apps. I In This way Think Your Problem Will be solved.

Comment: can you share some code or reference in your answer